# MATLAB estimateUncalibratedRectification non-deterministic behavior

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have written the function below to perform image rectification. I am using just the standard MATLAB library functions ([estimateUncalibratedRectification](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimateuncalibratedrectification.html) and [estimateFundamentalMatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimatefundamentalmatrix.html)) and my own wrapper function to MATLAB's [matchFeatures](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) to perform stereo rectification. Yet, with the **same inputs** I get different results every time. I know this is related to the use of RANSAC to estimate the fundamental matrix. However, the rectification is terrible sometimes and passable others. For example, over 10 different runs of my function with identical input, two results were okay, while 8 gave me variations on this error:

```
Warning: An epipole may be located inside of an image. The epipoles
are located at [285.8503,76.1656] in I1 and [265.5734,130.3931] in I2,
but the specified imageSize was [320,568]. Severe distortion may
result if T1 or T2 are used to transform these images. See
isEpipoleInImage for more information. 
> In coder.internal.warning (line 7)
  In cvalgEstimateUncalibratedRectification (line 114)
  In estimateUncalibratedRectification (line 107)
  In pairwiseTransformation (line 48)
```

I believe that this means that the rectification was unable to project the epipole to infinity.

What's going on here? It is worth noting that I have 279 putative matches and 32 inlierMatches between my images.

My function:

```
function [t1, t2] = pairwiseTransformation(img1, img2, features1, features2)

    % Identify putative matches
    [matches1, matches2] = matchFeaturePoints(rgb2gray(img1), features1, ...
        rgb2gray(img2), features2);

    % Estimate the fundamental matrix so that matches2' * F * matches1 = 0
    % F transforms matches1 to a line that runs through the corresponding
    % point in matches1. Therefore, any rotation and translation derived from F
    % (and E) will apply to camera 2's relative position, holding camera 1 fixed.
    [F, inliers] = estimateFundamentalMatrix(matches1, matches2, 'Method', 'RANSAC', ...
        'NumTrials', 2000, 'DistanceThreshold', 1e-4);

    % Use the RANSAC inliers to determine the relative position of img2 compared to img1
    inlierMatches1 = matches1(inliers, :);
    inlierMatches2 = matches2(inliers, :);


    [t1, t2] = estimateUncalibratedRectification(F, inlierMatches1, inlierMatches2, ...
        size(img1));

    r1 = imwarp(img1, projective2d(t1), 'OutputView', imref2d(size(img1)));
    r2 = imwarp(img2, projective2d(t2), 'OutputView', imref2d(size(img1)));

    figure;
    subplot(2,2,1),imshow(img1)
    subplot(2,2,2),imshow(img2)
    subplot(2,2,3),imshow(r1)
    subplot(2,2,4),imshow(r2)
end
```

Here's a decent rectification (top row is original images, bottom is rectified):

[image: Good]

And here's a totally botched effort that gave the epipole warning:

[image: Bad]

Comment: Taking another look, I guess that the botched effort is rectified, it's just that the result is crap.

Answer (score 0):

32 inlier matches seems too few...  How do your putative matches look?

One thing to try is to tweak the parameters of `estimateFundamentalMatrix`.  I would use `MSAC` instead of `RANSAC`, and increase the `DistanceThreshold` to something like .1 or even 1. At the same time you may want to increase the `Confidence` parameter, maybe to 99.99. That would force RANSAC to go through more trials, and increase your chances of finding the right solution.

The other thing to try is to get more and better putative matches from `matchFeatures`. You should try tweaking the parameters of your feature detector function to get more features, and then tweak the parameters of `matchFeatures` to make sure that the matches are still good. You can also try different detectors and descriptors.